# Audit Trail Access Log in Marketing Cloud gives me no results

Tags: marketing-cloud, setup-audit-log

I've followed all the steps in the official documentation to get the Audit Trail Access Log (https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_overview_audit_trail.htm&type=5) but I don't get any result.

I've got the Marketing Cloud Security Administrator role, I have enabled the feature in the Setup and I've logged in and logged out several times afterward to have records.

[image: Enable Audit Logging Data Collection]

I've set up an Automation with the Data Extract and the File Transfer:

[image: Data Extract]

[image: File Transfer]

But when I run it I get an empty csv all the time.

[image: CSV]

Does anyone has any idea about why is not working, please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you able to confirm if the audit trail is enabled under Setup > Security | Security Settings, > check Enable Audit Logging Data Collection? Otherwise, please try to extract from the parent/enterprise BU level.

Comment: There is a delay in writing to these logs, how long did you write after the action, and what action are you expecting to log?

Comment: Hello Brad! Yes, the audit trail is enabled (the first screenshot). I didn't try from the parent BU, I will do it :) but as per the documentation it should work from the child BU, right? Because what I need is the info from the BU I'm in.

Comment: Hello EazyE! I want to extract the Audit Trail Access Log. I set it up on the 27th, I have tried again today and I still get a file with no results, just the header.

Comment: Hello again @BradSapkota! You were right, thanks! I tried from the BU parent and I got the results. The only problem is that It doesn't say what BU did you log to...